# Java income tax form

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm a very new java student and am currently working on a program that I have been stuck on, it's an incremental program and it was working perfect with the first 2 tests and now I'm not sure what's happened. I will post my code below and hopefully someone can help me. Thanks! The scanner takes the input from the computer and is supposed to show something like this to the console:

AGI: $80,500
Deduction: $24,000
Taxable income: $56,500
Federal tax: $6,380
Tax refund: $5,620

it is supposed to test for these 2 first:

AGI: $120,523
Error: Income too high to use this form

which passed until I wrote the rest of the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class LabProgram {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  int wages;
  int taxableInterest;
  int unemploymentComp;
  int status;
  int taxWithheld;
  int AGI;
  int deduction;
  int fedTax;
  int Income;
  
  wages = scnr.nextInt();
  taxableInterest = scnr.nextInt();
  unemploymentComp = scnr.nextInt();
  
  AGI = (wages + taxableInterest + unemploymentComp);
  status = scnr.nextInt();
  Income = (AGI - status);
     
  
  if (AGI < 120000){
     System.out.printf("AGI: $%,d\n", AGI);
     
  }else{
     System.out.printf("AGI: $%,d\n", AGI);
     System.out.println("Error: Income too high to use this form");
     }
     
     Income = scnr.nextInt();
     if (Income > 0) {
        System.out.printf("Taxable income: $%,d\n", Income);
     }
     status = scnr.nextInt();
        if (status == 1) { 
           status = 12000;  
           System.out.printf("Deduction: $%,d\n",status);
           
           if (Income > 0 && Income <= 10000) {
                 System.out.printf("Federal tax: $%,d\n", (Math.round(Income * .10)));
              }
           else if (Income > 10001 && Income <= 40000) {
                 System.out.printf("Federal tax: $%,d\n", (Math.round(Income + 1000 *.20)));
              }
           else if (Income > 40001 && Income <= 85000) {
                 System.out.printf("Federal tax:$%,d\n ", (Math.round(Income +4600 *.20)));
              }
          else if (Income > 85000) {
                 System.out.printf("Federal tax: $%,d\n", (Math.round(Income + 14500 * .24)));
              }
        }
              
        if (status == 2){
           status = 24000;
           System.out.printf("Deduction: $%,d\n",status);
           
           if (Income > 0 && Income <= 20000) {
               System.out.printf("Federal tax: $%,d\n", (Math.round(Income * .10)));
           }   
           else if (Income > 20001 && Income < 80000) {
               System.out.printf("Federal tax: $%,d\n", (Math.round(Income + 2000 * .12)));
           }
           else if (Income > 80000) {
               System.out.printf("Federal tax: $%,d\n", (Math.round(Income + 9200 * .22)));
           }
        }
```

'''

Comment: Your code does print the error message, but then continues. You can e. g. add a return to the else-block. Regarding the Income-checks: as the code is executed sequentially, you can inverse the order of the if-statements. Then you don't need the logical and (&&) anymore. And please follow Java naming conventions.

Comment: Why continue after `System.out.println("Error: Income too high to use this form");` ?  Just exit?

Comment: I need the rest of it to be printed as well, I had it at the end of the code at first but it wouldn’t print.

Comment: Try moving different parts of your code into different methods, then you can call from wherever.